# IdFtp - Strange behavior when listing files

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

I am trying to list a ftp folder and them download all files from it. Here is the code:

```
oIDFTP.List;
if oIDFTP.ListResult.Count <> 1 then begin
  Exit;
end;
oIDFTP.Get(oIDFTP.ListResult[0], aFile, False, True);
```

But the oIDFTP.ListResult[0] contains this string:

```
03-20-12  05:49PM                    0 teste.txt
```

How can I list files without the time and date, only with the name like:

```
teste.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I found out the solution:

```
oIDFTP.List;
if oIDFTP.DirectoryListing.Count <> 1 then begin
  Exit;
end;
oIDFTP.Get(oIDFTP.DirectoryListing.Items[0].FileName, oIDFTP.DirectoryListing.Items[0].FileName, False, True);
```